# What can be passed to Lua functions as arguments?

Tags: function, lua, arguments

I've been searching through the documentation and through various questions, but I have not seen a plain answer to this question.  What types of values can be passed to Lua functions as arguments?

I believe the answer is:

- Plain old data such as Integer or Boolean
- Lua Tables
- other Lua functions

What I am looking for is a comprehensive list of what all can be passed into a function.

Comment: Eh... all values. Why would you expect there to be some restriction?

Comment: What if you try to pass in a raw object from another language for example?

Comment: Yes, even "raw object" as userdata can be passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Lua [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1):

> All values in Lua are first-class values. This means that all values can be stored in variables, passed as arguments to other functions, and returned as results.

Comment: So then the natural question is, what exactly qualifies as a value in Lua?

Comment: @bazola, the same section of the manual defines what values are.

Comment: In section 2.1 it says: There are eight basic types in Lua: nil, boolean, number, string, function, userdata, thread, and table.  Sorry, should have read the whole thing, but it is hard to find time!

Answer (score 1):

### vararg expression as an argument

In addition to passing any value as an argument, there is also an argument that is not a value: `...`, the "vararg expression."

It can only be used in the body of a function where it is a formal parameter. When used at the end of a list, it expands the list with all of the actual arguments it represents. When used before the end of a list, it expands the list only with the first actual argument it represents.

```
local function f(a, b, ...)
    print("f", a, b, ..., "end")
end

local function g(x, y, ...)
    print( "g", x, y, ...)
end

f()
f(1)
f(1,2)
f(1,2,3)
f(1,2,3,4)
f(1,2,3,4,5)
g()
g(1)
g(1,2)
g(1,2,3)
g(1,2,3,4)
g(1,2,3,4,5)
```